Program slows down when getting variables in multi threaded env
I have a kafka producer thread which I want to send realtime data from a video stream through a shared variable class.
Pseudocode it looks something like this, where G3LIB and Kafka is seperate threads.
Main program:
def main(): 
    shared_var = Shared_Variables(name="shared_variables")
    stream = G3LIB(shared_variables=shared_var)
    stream.start()

    kafka = Kafka_Producer(shared_variables=shared_var)
    kafka.start()
    stream.join()

In Kafka im currently getting the video stream from shared_variables where stream sets it.
Kafka:
def run(self):
    while True:
        img_frame = self.shared_variables.get_data("scene_frame_img") # makes it slow

The stream currently gets a new frame when its available.
Stream:
def run(self):
    while True:
        if new_frame_available:
            self._shr_var.set_data("scene_frame_img", frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24"))

The problem is that when running the kafka program it makes the whole program slow/lags. Other threads are also reading the scene_frame_img but has more delays for like 1 second but only stream is editing the variable.
To fix the problem I can have a delay for like 1 second. time.sleep(1).
This fixes the problem but I want to have realtime data flowing through so sleeping 1 second is not optimal.
